# Redirecting to an external URL in view file

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, view

I have the following string in a Spring MVC Controller action. I wanted the controller action to render a view page that takes this following string and then does the redirection.

```
String redirectUrl = "http://www.yahoo.com"
```

My controller action looks like the following:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showForm(HttpServletRequest request, ModelMap model) 
    {
          String redirectUrl = "http://www.yahoo.com";
          model.addAttribute("redirectUrl", redirectUrl);
          return "loginSuccess"; //this is my view JSP file
    }
```

Is there a way in JSP view to do this redirect without using JSTL? I want a clean redirect and not send any query string parameters.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I misunderstood but if you want a redirect, you'll have to use a `RedirectView`.

```
String redirectUrl = "http://www.yahoo.com";
return "redirect:" + redirectUrl;
```

Or use a `RedirectView` instance

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public View showForm(HttpServletRequest request, ModelMap model) 
{
      String redirectUrl = "http://www.yahoo.com";
      RedirectView view = new RedirectView(redirectUrl );
      return view;
}
```

Comment: This is definitely one approach, but I didn't want to redirect in the controller action.

Comment: @Jake You can return a `RedirectView` instance.

Comment: Just wanted the controller to a render a regular view and the view will take care of the URL redirection for me, instead of abruptly exiting out of the controller action.

Comment: @Jake If you wanted to use JSP to do the redirect, you would have to use scriplets and those are always bad. A `RedirectView` (or the redirect String) is the conventional way to do this.

Comment: It is possible that my controller action can render other views too depending on the condition.. Ex: here you only see "loginSuccess" being returned. It can return "loginError" as well.. So, I was wondering how RedirectView can come in handy. Can you modify my example and post a new one? Sorry.. I am a newbie here..

Comment: @Jake You change the return type to `View` and return a `RedirectView`. Returning the String would do the same thing down the `DispatcherServlet` call stack (converting the String to a view name, but because it starts with `redirect:`, that view would be a `RedirectView`). Here you do it directly.

Comment: okay..thank you for the example. that makes sense now.. I will try that out. In the mean time, will your example handle a loop like this? if (error) { return "loginError"; } //Here loginError is a JSP view. If so, how?

Comment: @Jake What do you mean _handle a loop_? You're returning a String. Spring will transform that string to a view name and forward the request/response to the corresponding JSP.

Comment: Oh okay.. So, if I wanted to render a loginError.jsp instead of an external redirect URL, all I need to do is:

RedirectView errorView = new RedirectView("loginError" );
return errorView;

Comment: @Jake Have a look at the [javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/RedirectView.html). What you just showed will cause a 303 response. If you're on a browser, that'll cause it to send a new HTTP GET request to `www.yourhost.com/yourApp/loginError`. If you want to send to a compltely different host, you need to put the whole url `http://www.yahoo.com`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36556/discussion-between-jake-and-sotirios-delimanolis)